# How do I use SortCompare with dataGridView in a WindowsFormsApp

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to sort a column of a dataGridView in c#, but it doesn't seem to sort any differently. I don't think the sortCompare event is firing. I even added a breakpoint in the SortCompare method, and it was never reached

I have this code in my Form method, and the code after it is how the SortCompare method looks.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGrid.SortCompare += new DataGridViewSortCompareEventHandler(
        this.dataGrid_SortCompare);
    }

private void dataGrid_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
    {
        // Try to sort based on the cells in the current column.
        int intValue1, intValue2;

        if (!Int32.TryParse(e.CellValue1.ToString(), out intValue1))
            return;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(e.CellValue2.ToString(), out intValue2))
            return;

        if (intValue1 == intValue2)
            e.SortResult = 0;
        else if (intValue1 < intValue2)
            e.SortResult = -1;
        else
            e.SortResult = 1;

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

I have all columns set to Automatic sorting, have virtual mode set to false, and the dataSource is a dataTable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Reading the documentation can be helpful at times. The “Remarks” section will usually contain info that describes how this feature may not work under certain circumstances. And this applies to your question, in the first sentence in the “Remarks” section states that… [_”This event occurs only when the DataSource property is not set…”_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortcompare?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) … note the “not set.” … along with the last sentence of your question… _”and the dataSource is a dataTable.”_ …

Comment: Also, it seems odd that the code in the `SortCompare` is simply checking two `int` values. This is a basic sort and given you are using a `DataTable`, then, technically, it “should” still sort the grid without any additional code. For a more exotic sort, then the `DataTable` can also be sorted. Since I would encourage using a data source for the grid, it would appear your solution lies in sorting the `DataTable`.